# Spring Cloud Consul health check and status configuration on GCP

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-consul

We are trying to register a [spring-cloud-consul](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/single/spring-cloud-consul.html) application with [consul](https://www.consul.io/docs/index.html) on [GCP compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/), where it is able to register the application with the consul, but there are two problems we are facing with the application. Below is **`bootstrap.yaml`** and **server.yaml** for the application,

**`application.yaml`**

```
server:
  port: 10003
spring:
  application:
    name: hello-service
  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: true
    inetutils:
      useOnlySiteLocalInterfaces: true
  endpoints:
    actuator:
      sensitive: false
```

**`bootstrap.yaml`**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: true
      host: 10.160.0.18
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        prefer-ip-address: true
```

1. Consul is not able to call health-check on compute engine, possibly because it's registered on the internal domain name of the instance.

> service with consul: NewService{id='hello-service-10003',
>   name='hello-service', tags=[secure=false],
>   address='consul-app-test.c.name-of-project.internal', meta=null,
>   port=10003, enableTagOverride=null, check=Check{script='null',
>   interval='10s', ttl='null',
>   http='http://consul-app-test.c.name-of-project.internal:10003/actuator/health',
>   method='null', header={}, tcp='null', timeout='null',
>   deregisterCriticalServiceAfter='null', tlsSkipVerify=null,
>   status='null'}, checks=null}

2. Application, not de-registering from the consul. We have stopped the application still it shows on consul UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes in the ***application.yaml*** and ***bootstrap.yaml*** which worked for me.

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: hello-service
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${random.value}
        health-check-critical-timeout: 3m
        prefer-ip-address: true # disable if we want to use google cloud internal DNS
```

**bootstrap.yaml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: true
      host: 10.160.0.18
      port: 8500
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use version `2.1.2` like me: `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:2.1.2.RELEASE`

you can set:

```
spring:

  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost #  consul的地址
      port: 8500 # consul 的端口
      discovery:
        prefer-ip-address: true  # // This must be matched
        tags: version=1.0
        instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.cloud.client.ip-address}
        healthCheckPath: /actuator/health # 服务做健康检查的端口
        healthCheckInterval: 15s  # 服务健康检查的周期
        healthCheckTimeout: 60s # 服务检查是的timeout时长
        healthCheckCriticalTimeout: 5m # 服务健康检查失败5分钟后，删除服务
```

and you can look the source code in `ConsulDiscoveryProperties`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.consul.discovery")
public class ConsulDiscoveryProperties {

……

    /** Is service discovery enabled? */
    private boolean enabled = true;

    /** Alternate server path to invoke for health checking. */
    private String healthCheckPath = "/actuator/health";

    /** Custom health check url to override default. */
    private String healthCheckUrl;

    /** How often to perform the health check (e.g. 10s), defaults to 10s. */
    private String healthCheckInterval = "10s";

    /** Timeout for health check (e.g. 10s). */
    private String healthCheckTimeout;

    /**
     * Timeout to deregister services critical for longer than timeout (e.g. 30m).
     * Requires consul version 7.x or higher.
     */
    private String healthCheckCriticalTimeout;
……
```